# How to setup Compass in refinery CMS without refinery-theming plugin?

Tags: compass-sass, refinerycms

According [this discussion](http://groups.google.com/group/refinery-cms/browse_thread/thread/69a01dce11e41738), refinery-theming plugin is required while using Compass in refinery CMS. But [refinery-theming's page](https://github.com/resolve/refinerycms-theming) said it's no longer command to use it. Is there anyway to use Compass in refinery without theming plugin? Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I am using Compass in a Refinery site by doing the following:

1) Add Compass dependencies to your Gemfile:

```
gem "compass"
gem "haml"
```

2) Run bundle install

3) Initialise the app for compass

```
compass init rails /path/to/myrailsproject
```

4) Override the Refinery shared/_head.html.erb partial:

```
rake refinery:override view=shared/_head
```

5) Add following stylesheet link tags to shared/_head.html.erb:

```
<%= stylesheet_link_tag 'screen', :media => 'screen, projection' %>
<%= stylesheet_link_tag 'print', :media => 'print' %>

<!--[if IE ]>
<%= stylesheet_link_tag 'ie.css', :media => 'screen, projection' %>
<![endif]-->
```

6) Personally I remove all other stylesheet_link_tag's from shared/_head.html.erb

7) Your styles should now be added to app/stylesheets/screen.scss and included partials

Comment: Thank you! Of note: in the latest version of Refinery the override becomes: `rake refinery:override view=refinery/_head`.